# Saving binary file from base64 text data by IE, ADODB.Stream to hard disk

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, adodb

I had a problem when try to saving a binary file by IE, ADODB.Stream on client.

Assume the the client's browser has full permission to write file to hard disk.

Here is my client code witten by javascript.:

```
var base64_encoded_string = "base64 string of a binary file";
var data = window.atob(base64_encoded_string);
var stream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
stream.Type = 1; // text
stream.Open();
stream.Write(data); //Problem in here
stream.SaveToFile("D:\\Whatever.pfx", 2);
stream.Close();
```

As I marked problem come from writing binary data. I always got error:

**"Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another"**

Whatever I format or change data variable to array of bytes, blob ...

Please help me how to input data to write binary file in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `WriteText`

```
stream.WriteText(data);
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer works, instead of just giving it.