# Upload Image with vbscript classic asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, vbscript

I am building a part of our mobile application where I am trying to let the click on choose a file they choose a picture or take one with their camera. I am having trouble with after that user chose the picture I then want to upload it into our imaging database so I am using ajax to post it to an asp page and then trying to decode the base64 string and then upload it into the database. Our database only accepts binary data and I am having a really hard time accomplishing this step it any help would be appreciated.

html

```
 <button id="chooseFile" data-theme="b" data-icon="camera">Choose      file</button>
    <div class="hiddenfile">
         <input type="file"  data-clear-btn="false" id="PicFile" name="PicFile" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
    </div>
        <div id="preview">
        </div>
        <ul id="info" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="hiddenButton" id="hiddenButton">
        <button id="upload" name="upload" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-u" onclick="return PicUpload ()">Upload</button>
        </div>

</div>
```

javascript that builds the picture as an base 64 string

```
   var hiddenbutton = $("#hiddenButton");
hiddenbutton.hide();
$('#page').live('pageinit', function(){
    $("#chooseFile").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
    });
    $("input[type=file]").change(function(){
        var file = $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0];
        $("#preview").empty();
        displayAsImage3(file, "preview");
        $info = $("#info");
        $info.empty();
        if (file && file.name) {
            $info.append("<li>This is just a preview click the upload button below to upload the picture</li>")
        }
        if (file && file.name) {
            $info.append(hiddenbutton.show());
        }
        $info.listview("refresh");

    });
});

function displayAsImage3(file, containerid) {
    if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
        var container = document.getElementById(containerid),
            img = document.createElement("img"),
            reader;
        container.appendChild(img);
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theImg) {
            return function (evt) {
                theImg.src = evt.target.result;
            };
        }(img));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }




}
```

my ajax that is grabbing that element and passing it to my asp page

```
   function PicUpload () {
    var strDocType;
    var strImage;
    var strPath;
    var strPicExtension;
    var strDOTInfo;
    var strFileType;
    var strFileID;
    var image;
    var imgsomething;




 strDocType = "<%=strDocType%>";
 strImage = ($('img')[0].src);
 strPicExtension = strImage.substring(11, 14)
 strDOTInfo = $("#txtDotInformation").val();
 strFileType = "";
 strFileID = "";
 image = "";
 imgsomething = "";






if (strPicExtension == "jpe") {
    strFileType = "image/jpeg"
}

if (strPicExtension == "gif") {
    strFileType = "image/gif"
}

if (strPicExtension == "png") {
    strFileType = "image/png"
}


if (strPicExtension != "jpe") {
    strPath = strImage.substring(22);
}
else {
    strPath = strImage.substring(23);
}


if (strDOTInfo == "") {
        alert("You must enter the DOT Information")
        $("#txtDotInformation").focus();
        return false;
        }

    if (strDocType == "CALLUPLOAD") {
        var strCallID;
        var strDOTID;
        var strDOTSizeCode;
        var intDOTDateCode;

        strCallID = "<%=strCallID%>";
        strDOTID = strDOTInfo.substring(0,2);
        strDOTSizeCode = strDOTInfo.substring(2,4);
        intDOTDateCode = strDOTInfo.substring(4,8);

        if (strCallID == "") {
        alert("There has to be a call ID")
        return false;
        }


      image =  btoa(strPath);








        jQuery('#pics').html ('<img src="/GYGlobal/images/icons/ajax-  loader.gif"> Uploading Pic . . .');
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/tools/document_picture_ajax.asp",
                data: 'hidAjaxAction=PicUpload&hidDOTID='+strDOTID+'&hidDOTSizeCode='+strDOTSizeCode+'&hidDOTDateCode='+intDOTDateCode+'&hidCallID='+strCallID+'&hidFileType='+strFileType+'&hidDocType='+strDocType,
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false,
                success: function(data){

                    strFileID = data



                }
            }
        );


        jQuery('#pics').html ('<img src="/GYGlobal/images/icons/ajax-loader.gif"> Uploading Pic . . .');
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/tools/document_picture_ajax.asp",
                data: 'hidAjaxAction=PicUploadFile&hidFileID='+strFileID+'&hidObjFileData='+image+'&hidDocType='+strDocType,
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#preview").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#info").fadeOut("slow");
                    AfterPicUpload ()




                }
            }
        );




}
```

Now my asp page code that is putting everything in the database and the functions that I found to decode base64 string

```
 Case "PicUpload":

Select Case (strDocType)
 Case "CALLUPLOAD":
 Set objImagingFile = New clsImagingIndex
    With objImagingFile

        .intBatchID         = 0
        .strLocation        = gstrLocation
        .strDepartment      = "FleetHQ"
        .strDocumentType    = "Breakdown Photo"
        .strStatus          = "COMPLETE"
        .strKey1                = strCallID
        .strKey2                = strDOTID
        .strKey3                = strDOTSizeCode
        .strKey4                = intDOTDateCode
        .strFileName        = "Call Upload" & " " & strCallID
        .strFileType        = strFileType
        .strAddUser         = gstrUserID
        .strUpdUser         = gstrUserID
        .intFilePageNum = 1
        .Insert()
        intFileID           = .intFileID
        Response.Write intFileID
  End With
  Set objImagingFile = Nothing
  Case "DR":
    Set objImagingFile = New clsImagingIndex
    With objImagingFile
        .intBatchID         = 0
        .strLocation        = gstrLocation
        .strDepartment      = "Sales"
        .strDocumentType    = "Document Photo"
        .strStatus          = "COMPLETE"
        .strKey1                = strLocation
        .strKey2                = strDocType
        .strKey3                = strDocNumber
        .strKey4                = strDocVendor
        .strFileName        = strOriginalFileName
        .strFileType        = strFileType
        .strAddUser         = gstrUserID
        .strUpdUser         = gstrUserID
        .intFilePageNum = 1
        .Insert()
        intFileID           = .intFileID
    End With
    Set objImagingFile = Nothing
Case "IN":
    Set objImagingFile = New clsImagingIndex
    With objImagingFile
        .intBatchID         = 0
         .strLocation       = gstrLocation
        .strDepartment      = "Sales"
        .strDocumentType    = "Document Photo"
        .strStatus          = "COMPLETE"
        .strKey1                = strLocation
        .strKey2                = strDocType
        .strKey3                = strDocNumber
        .strKey4                = strDocVendor
        .strFileName        = strOriginalFileName
        .strFileType        = strFileType
        .strAddUser         = gstrUserID
        .strUpdUser         = gstrUserID
        .intFilePageNum = 1
        .Insert()
        intFileID           = .intFileID
    End With
    Set objImagingFile = Nothing
 End Select

  Case "PicUploadFile":
   Dim objPicData
   Dim objPictureData

  'Response.Write strPath

 objPicData = Base64Decode(strPath)

 Response.Write objPicData

 objPictureData = Base64Decode(objPicData)

 Response.Write objPictureData

    Select Case (strDocType)
    Case "CALLUPLOAD":

    Set objImagingData = New clsImagingData
    With objImagingData
        .intFileID          = intFileID
        .dteDiskExpDate = "90" 'days to add to current date
        .dteDiskExpDate = DateAdd("d",30,Date())
        .objFileData        = objPictureData
        .Insert()
        'Call AddCallPictureCount
    End With
    Set objImagingData = Nothing

    Case "DR":
    Set objImagingData = New clsImagingData
    With objImagingData
        .intFileID          = intFileID
        .dteDiskExpDate = DateAdd("d",30,Date())
        .objFileData        = objFileData
        .Insert()
    Call AddDocumentPictureCount
    End With
    Set objImagingData = Nothing
    Case "IN":
    Set objImagingData = New clsImagingData
    With objImagingData
        .intFileID          = intFileID
        .dteDiskExpDate = "90" 'days to add to current date
        .dteDiskExpDate = DateAdd("d",30,Date())
        .objFileData        = objFileData
        .Insert()
     Call AddDocumentPictureCount
    End With
    Set objImagingData = Nothing
End Select

   Function Base64Decode(ByVal strPath)
   'rfc1521
  '1999 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz
  Const Base64 =   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  Dim dataLength, sOut, groupBegin



 'remove white spaces, If any
 strPath = Replace(strPath, vbCrLf, "")
 strPath = Replace(strPath, vbTab, "")
  strPath = Replace(strPath, " ", "")

  'The source must consists from groups with Len of 4 chars
  dataLength = Len(strPath)
  If dataLength Mod 4 <> 0 Then
   Err.Raise 1, "Base64Decode", "Bad Base64 string."
   Exit Function
 End If


  ' Now decode each group:
  For groupBegin = 1 To dataLength Step 4
   Dim numDataBytes, CharCounter, thisChar, thisData, nGroup, pOut
   ' Each data group encodes up To 3 actual bytes.
   numDataBytes = 3
    nGroup = 0

   For CharCounter = 0 To 3
  ' Convert each character into 6 bits of data, And add it To
  ' an integer For temporary storage.  If a character is a '=', there
  ' is one fewer data byte.  (There can only be a maximum of 2 '=' In
  ' the whole string.)

  thisChar = Mid(strPath, groupBegin + CharCounter, 1)

  If thisChar = "=" Then
    numDataBytes = numDataBytes - 1
    thisData = 0
  Else
    thisData = InStr(1, Base64, thisChar, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
  End If
  If thisData = -1 Then
    Err.Raise 2, "Base64Decode", "Bad character In Base64 string."
    Exit Function
  End If

  nGroup = 64 * nGroup + thisData
   Next

'Hex splits the long To 6 groups with 4 bits
nGroup = Hex(nGroup)


'Add leading zeros
nGroup = String(6 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup

'Convert the 3 byte hex integer (6 chars) To 3 characters
pOut = Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2))) + _
  Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2))) + _
  Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)))

'add numDataBytes characters To out string
sOut = sOut & Left(pOut, numDataBytes)
  Next

  Base64Decode = sOut
End Function

   Function Base64Decode(ByVal objPicData)
  'rfc1521
  '1999 Antonin Foller, Motobit Software, http://Motobit.cz
 Const Base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
  Dim dataLength, sOut, groupBegin



 'remove white spaces, If any
 objPicData = Replace(objPicData, vbCrLf, "")
 objPicData = Replace(objPicData, vbTab, "")
  objPicData = Replace(objPicData, " ", "")

'The source must consists from groups with Len of 4 chars
dataLength = Len(objPicData)
 If dataLength Mod 4 <> 0 Then
  Err.Raise 1, "Base64Decode", "Bad Base64 string."
  Exit Function
  End If


 ' Now decode each group:
  For groupBegin = 1 To dataLength Step 4
  Dim numDataBytes, CharCounter, thisChar, thisData, nGroup, pOut
   ' Each data group encodes up To 3 actual bytes.
   numDataBytes = 3
   nGroup = 0

   For CharCounter = 0 To 3
  ' Convert each character into 6 bits of data, And add it To
  ' an integer For temporary storage.  If a character is a '=', there
  ' is one fewer data byte.  (There can only be a maximum of 2 '=' In
  ' the whole string.)

    thisChar = Mid(objPicData, groupBegin + CharCounter, 1)

    If thisChar = "=" Then
    numDataBytes = numDataBytes - 1
    thisData = 0
  Else
    thisData = InStr(1, Base64, thisChar, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
  End If
  If thisData = -1 Then
    Err.Raise 2, "Base64Decode", "Bad character In Base64 string."
    Exit Function
  End If

  nGroup = 64 * nGroup + thisData
   Next

'Hex splits the long To 6 groups with 4 bits
nGroup = Hex(nGroup)

'Add leading zeros
nGroup = String(6 - Len(nGroup), "0") & nGroup

'Convert the 3 byte hex integer (6 chars) To 3 characters
pOut = Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 1, 2))) + _
  Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 3, 2))) + _
  Chr(CByte("&H" & Mid(nGroup, 5, 2)))

'add numDataBytes characters To out string
sOut = sOut & Left(pOut, numDataBytes)
  Next

Base64Decode = sOut
End Function
```

Now it runs through the functions just fine after I encode the base64string with btoa() method in javascript, however If I do not double encode it does not run it says bad base64 string. I do not know if I need to save the image some how then get it back out of a folder and put it into binary with vbscript. If that is what I need to do how do I get the image out of this base64 and saved into a folder with a .jpeg name?

Comment: this is the picture string or part of it I am taking everything after the base64 comma  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwkHBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx4WFxIZJCAmJSMgIyIoLTkwKCo2KyIjMkQyNjs9QEBAJjBGS0U+Sjk/QD3/2wBDAQsLCw8NDx0QEB09KSMpPT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT3/wAARCADHASwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving binary file from base64 text data by IE, ADODB.Stream to hard disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055323/saving-binary-file-from-base64-text-data-by-ie-adodb-stream-to-hard-disk)